# libgdx: using preferences causes lags

Tags: java, android, libgdx, save, lag

When i use preferences to save data in libgdx project:

1. game freez for 2-3 secs at GameOver (moment that most prefs keys had been saved)
2. after long time playing game starts to lag even in game process

If i reduce amount of keys - game works fine (for 1st problem). If i delete .prefs file - game runs smoothly, but not for long time (for 2nd problem).

I'm using the following code to save data:

```
 prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("GameName");

    if (!prefs.contains("highScore")) {
        prefs.putInteger("highScore", 0);
    }
    if (!prefs.contains("caracterChosen")) {
        prefs.putInteger("caracterChosen", 1);
    }
    if (!prefs.contains("blueRingsNum")) {
        prefs.putInteger("blueRingsNum", 0);
    }
```

-

```
public static void setHighScore(int val) {
    prefs.putInteger("highScore", val);
    prefs.flush();
}
```

etc. I've got about 20 keys to save and i will need even more keys. What could be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak to me. Try opening task manager when playing on desktop and check if memory used by your game is constantly raising. Also you shouldn't read/write prefs for every frame, but do it on beginning/end of options screen, play screen or other key moments.

Comment: Are you doing this in your render method?
edit: If so, take it out of there.

Comment: @MilanG thanks a lot! I //commented 1 method in render that was reading prefs data every frame and 2nd problem dissapeared. Also i'll try rethink how to write prefs to avoid lags (1st problem).